# How to duplicate a record/document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I want to duplicate my document based on a field in MongoDB.
Refer to this documents below:

`a:1,b:2,c:3,
a:2,b:2,c:3,
a:1,b:4,c:3,
a:2,b:2,c:3,
a:1,b:5,c:6`

So, i want duplicates of the documents where a=1.

Output should be like this:

`a:1,b:2,c:3,
a:2,b:2,c:3,
a:1,b:4,c:3,
a:2,b:2,c:3,
a:1,b:5,c:6,
a:1,b:2,c:3,
a:1,b:4,c:3,
a:1,b:5,c:6`

Comment: use mongo aggregation with $out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're doing this using the [`mongo` Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/), one approach could be to iterate a query cursor as follows:

```
db.collection.find({ a: 1 }, { _id: 0 }).forEach(function(doc) {
    db.collection.insert(doc);
});
```

What the above code does is:

1. Query for all documents that match `a = 1`
2. Project the result *without* an [_id](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field)
3. Iterate the cursor using a [`forEach`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) method
4. [Insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) a copy of the document into the source collection.

Note the insert creates a copy as we've removed the original document's `_id`. MongoDB will automatically create this value (using an [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)) if it is not specified.

Comment: Thanks!! @Alex ,This works but i didn't get why did you put `{ _id: 0 }` in the query?

Comment: To project the results of the query without an _id field. Without this, the docs would come back as { _id: ObjectId("xxxxxx"), a:1,b:2,c:3 } and an `insert` would fail as a duplicate _id would be detected

Comment: @AlexB. Can you edit answer, removing incorrect closing bracket, after `(function(doc)`.
I tried to edit, but need to edit a minimum number of characters. No need to edit an answer that's otherwise perfect.

Comment: @AlexB. right after the `insert` happens, how can I `convert` and `increment` a value into one field for the copied document only?

Comment: @GuilhermeMatheus, it would likely be better to ask a new question for this, but using an aggregation pipeline you could match these documents, manipulate them and $merge the  results back to the source collection.